# Folder with dark triangles in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode9

In my project by mistake I created a group without folder. Now I want to make its folder in file structure too. How to remove dark triangles in Xcode folders? So that it will exist as a folder in file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove dark triangles in Xcode folders? So that it will exist as a folder in file structure.

I think the dark triangle you're talking about is the one in the corner of the folder icon, like this:

[image: Xcode group icon]

There's no option to convert a group to a folder, but you can always just create a new folder (File->New->Group with Folder) and then move the files that are in the group in question into that new folder. Then delete the old group if you no longer need it.

Comment: I followed the same approach.So there is no other way.is it?

Comment: What other way is needed? This is three quick steps to complete a task that comes up only rarely. I'd rather have that than a special-purpose command that makes Xcode bigger and requires development and testing resources that could be better spent on making Xcode better.